# Update with Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, updates

I want to update items by Entity Framework,

The code is correct but i don't have result in my database!!

```
using(checkinentrepriseEntities2 context = new checkinentrepriseEntities2()) {
 clients clien = new clients();

 clien.date_arrival = DateTime.Parse(textBoxDateIN.Text);
 clien.arrival_time = textBoxTIME.Text;
 clien.Aller_A = comboboxPersonnel.SelectedItem.ToString();
 clien.Badge = int.Parse(comboBoxBadge.SelectedItem.ToString());

 int badgeTiped = int.Parse(comboBoxBadge.SelectedItem.ToString());

 context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: You're creating a new `clients` so you will be inserting and not updating in this situation, meaning you also need `context.clients.Add(clien)` or something along those lines

Comment: do you want add a new `Client` or update an existing `Client`?

Comment: `context.clients.Add(clien)`

Comment: OH! i make mistake...
I want update an existing Client not Add !!  Very Thakns!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is creating a new `clients` object.

If you want to update results from the database you have to select the `clients` object from the database :

```
clients clien = context.clients.Single(x => x.Id == yourId);
// your logic
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: That is it !! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code:

```
        using (checkinentrepriseEntities2 context = new checkinentrepriseEntities2())
        {
            clients clien = new clients();

            clien.date_arrival = DateTime.Parse(textBoxDateIN.Text);
            clien.arrival_time = textBoxTIME.Text;
            clien.Aller_A = comboboxPersonnel.SelectedItem.ToString();
            clien.Badge = int.Parse(comboBoxBadge.SelectedItem.ToString());

            int badgeTiped = int.Parse(comboBoxBadge.SelectedItem.ToString());

            context.clients.Add(clien);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Just add `context.clients.Add(clien);`